# Flutter WebView Show Media Controls in Notification Bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a Flutter application in which I have a webview using
[Flutter InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

I have loaded a url which has radio streams inside and everything works fine, even when I go to background mode or I lock device I can hear the music. The problem is that I don't have any media controls, for example play-pause.

If I open the same link in my phone browser (using Android & iOS), play the stream and locked device I have media controls including art cover.

So my question is, is it possible to add Media Controls in Notification bar if I use WebView inside my Flutter application?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Still no solution